# how to unfreeze panes in OpenPyxl 3.1.2?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm working with Excel files that have the panes frozen, and I need to return a worksheet in which they've been unfrozen.

Something like the following causes an error when the resulting workbook is opened in excel. Clicking through the error does result in a workbook that appears to be fine, but may cause alarm in users that may be less computer-proficient.

```
ws.freeze_panes=ws["A1"]
```

A solution suggested in 2018, seen below, does not appear to work correctly in OpenPyxl 3.1.2.

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
ws = wb.active
ws.views.sheetView[0].pane = openpyxl.worksheet.views.Pane() # makes pane empty
ws.views.sheetView[0].selection[0] = openpyxl.worksheet.views.Selection()
ws.views.sheetView[0].topLeftCell = 'A1' # scroll to top left corner
wb.save(filename)
```

Is there a way to unfreeze panes in OpenPyxl 3.1.2?

Comment: If you can use Xlwings this module will unfreeze without error when opening the work book/sheet.

Comment: Pane and Selection seem to go hand in hand so setting then to `None` and `()` should probably suffice.

Answer (score 0):

The command is

```
ws.freeze_panes = "A1"
```

and

```
ws.freeze_panes = None
```

would **unfreeze** column or row.
Then

```
ws.freeze_panes = "<Any other column but 'A'>1"
```

will freeze columns to the left of the column entered, and

```
ws.freeze_panes = "<Column 'A'><Any row but 1>"
```

will freeze the rows above the row number entered.
Finally

```
ws.freeze_panes = "<Any other column but 'A'><Any row but 1>"
```

will freeze the rows/columns above and left of the cell.

**Note** If you do unfreeze using Openpyxl you will get an error on opening the work book/sheet. This appears to be still a thing with Openpyxl and may be an issue to the sheet or users as you have mentioned.

The other method is kinda what the Openpyxl function does.

```
ws.views.sheetView[0].pane = openpyxl.worksheet.views.Pane() # makes pane empty
ws.views.sheetView[0].selection[0] = openpyxl.worksheet.views.Selection()
ws.views.sheetView[0].topLeftCell = 'A1' # scroll to top left corner
```

I tried it with Openpyxl 3.1.2. It did clear a single row or column freeze without causing an error on work book/sheet open, but did when  there was a freeze on both row and column.
Given I don't know the specific reason (it's probably to do with the OOXML API) for the error your results may be different.